# How can I remove this dangerous insect from my garden?

Tags: insects

There is an insect in my garden that I would like to remove. It lives in a garden covered in pine bark. My location is Miami, FL. It can deliver a sting/bite that can last 5 days or more:

Given the severity of the bite I want it removed from all my gardens, as opposed to the "just wear gloves" solution . What should I do?

Remove all the pine bark, do "something" to the soil, put in new pine bark? What about using cypress mulch?

Comment: You're asking us to identify an insect based on a picture of your thumb?

Comment: It may not be an insect anyway, it might be your reaction to the sap of a particular plant you pulled up. Always best to wear gloves...

Comment: Based on your location and my own experience with the little bastards, I have to say that looks like a fire ant bite to me.

Comment: @Escoce I sure thought I knew what fire ants were. Looks like what got me is invasive from S. America. I am in awe that a tiny ant could create such a long lasting welt. unbelievable. The initial contact definitely felt like a sting... well, at least I didn't sit on the fire ants' nest (it is not a mound).

Comment: Stung (by fire ant?) 8 days ago, and... the wound has not changed much. Now I'm hoping it leaves a permanent mark. Natural tattoos are pretty cool. :-)